# c++11 bind: difference between using and not-using placeholder

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
  1 #include <functional>
  2 #include <iostream>
  3 
  4 using namespace std::placeholders;
  5 
  6 void update23(int i1, int &i2, int &i3)
  7 {
  8     i2 += i1;
  9     i3 += i2;
 10 
 11     std::cout << i2 << "  " << i3 << std::endl;
 12 }
 13 
 19 
 20 int main()
 21 {
 22     int i1 = 10, i2 = 20, i3 = 30;
 23 
 26     std::bind(update23, 10, 20, 30)();
 27     std::bind(update23, 10, _1, _2)(20, 30);
 28       
 29     return 0;
 30 }
```

Line 27 fails in compiling. The failure makes sense because constant are being passed as references.

Why does line 26 pass though?

I checked c++ bind source, but quickly got lost.

If you could lead me through the bind source to understand what is the magic here, would appreciate it very much!

Comment: `std::bind` copies the bound arguments and stores them as lvalues to be later passed to the callback.

Comment: @Cthulhu They are defined in `<functional>`

Comment: the code compiles fine for me. Seems your compiler fails to optimize it. I am using vs2012

Answer (score 2):

As usual, you cannot call a function that expects a mutable lvalue reference (such as the result of the second `bind` expression) with temporary values.

The first version works because the bound values are captured by value and provided to the call as lvalues.

You can either change the function signature or change the call to:

```
std::bind(update23, 10, _1, _2)(i2, i3);
```

Comment: it seems that VS2012 can optimize line 27 and still compile. At least it does for me.

Comment: @cageman: MSVS is infamously C++-noncompliant. "Proof by it-compiles" doesn't work, unfortunately :-)